# Fine tuning MS SQL server query joining two tables with grouped result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I would like to ask you if there's efficient way to write a query to retrieve the data from tables provided below and display only the columns and values I want. I already wrote two queries however the first one is a bit slow and in the second I got more columns than I want.

So here are my three tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here's the output I want:
[image]

Output table should display monthly values from Jan till Dec.
In the real database Table A has ~40k rows, Table B has 20 rows and Table C has ~1 million rows.
Below you can see part of a query which I wrote and which generate desired output, however when I ran it for real DB it takes ~20-30 seconds:

```
  SELECT TableA.Id
    ,TableA.Title
    ,TableA.Description
    ,TableB.Title
    ,f1.[Value] as TableC_JanuaryValue
    ,f2.[Value] as TableC_FebruaryValue
    ....
    FROM <tablename>
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.Id = TableA.TableB_FK_Id
INNER JOIN TableC as f1 ON (f1.TableA_FK_Id = TableA.Id AND f1.[Year] = 2018 AND f1.[Month] = 1)
INNER JOIN TableC as f2 ON (f2.TableA_FK_Id = TableA.Id AND f2.[Year] = 2018 AND f2.[Month] = 2)
.....
```

I was trying to write it differently and make it faster and I managed to get it down to 2-3 seconds, however the output is not exactly what I want. 
Here's the second query:

```
  SELECT TableA.Id
    ,TableA.Title
    ,TableA.Description
    ,TableB.Title
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V1' and TableC.[Month] = 1 then TableC.Id end) as JAN_IsV1
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V2' and TableC.[Month] = 1 then TableC.Id end) as JAN_IsV2
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V3' and TableC.[Month] = 1 then TableC.Id end) as JAN_IsV3
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V1' and TableC.[Month] = 2 then TableC.Id end) as FEB_IsV1
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V2' and TableC.[Month] = 2 then TableC.Id end) as FEB_IsV2
    ,count(case when TableC.Value = 'V3' and TableC.[Month] = 2 then TableC.Id end) as FEB_IsV3
    ....
    FROM <tablename>
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.Id = TableA.TableB_FK_Id
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.Id = TableC.TAbleA_FK_Id
where TableC.[Year] = 2018
group by TableA.Id, TableA.Title, TableA.Description, TableB.Title
```

And here's what I get:
[image]

I know that its very close to the result I want, however its not exactly the same :(

Comment: Matbailie, Thanks! I missed that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the pivoting on TableC ***before*** you join it to the others. And use `MAX(CASE)` instead of `COUNT(CASE)`

```
SELECT
    TableA.Id
    ,TableA.Title
    ,TableA.Description
    ,TableB.Title
    ,TableC.*
FROM
    TableA
INNER JOIN
    TableB
        ON TableB.Id = TableA.TableB_FK_Id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        TableA_FK_Id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1 THEN Value END) AS JAN,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2 THEN Value END) AS FEB, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = 3 THEN Value END) AS MAR, 
        ...
    FROM
        TableC
    WHERE
        [YEAR] = 2018
    GROUP BY
        TableA_FK_Id
)
    TableC
        ON TableA.Id = TableC.TableA_FK_Id
```

Comment: Not only it works, but it works in a second ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT 
       tablea.Id AS TableA_Id,  
       tablea.Title AS TableA_Title, 
       tablea.Description AS TableA_Description,
       (SELECT tableb.Title FROM tableb WHERE tableb.Id = TableA.TableB_FK_Id) AS TableB_Id,
       (SELECT tablec.Value FROM tablec WHERE tablea.Id = TableC.TableA_FK_Id AND tablec.Month = 1) AS TableC_JanValue,
       (SELECT tablec.Value FROM tablec WHERE tablea.Id = TableC.TableA_FK_Id  AND tablec.Month = 2) AS TableC_FebValue
FROM tablea;
```

this one also u can try..!! :)